# How to 'pipe' or 'chain' output of a server socket to the input of another server socket similar to sendfile?

Tags: linux, sockets, sendfile

In Linux, using sendfile you can directly transfer file out to a socket.

But let's say we have two server socket, we want to the output of the first one to go out to the second one.

How to do that?
Instead of

```
data=sock1.read()
sock2.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [dup2](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) will work

Comment: what? how? dup2 duplicates file descriptors. The question is `we have two server socket, we want to the output of the first one to go out to the second one`

Comment: Sockets *are* file descriptors. After `dup2` whenever someone writes to the first one it's as if they wrote to the second. In this situation there is no "output from the first one", it collapses completely.

Comment: Show how it works. If both sockets are under the process' control then obviously there would be no problem eliminating the intermediate transfer?